# Remove Pycharm completely , Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

I want to remove my old pycharm completely from my Ubuntu machine so my new installation will not be affected from previous settings. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try the following commands
it will completely delete the pycharm with its preferences from ubuntu.

```
rm -fv /usr/local/bin/charm
rm -rfv ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm?0
rm -rfv ~/Library/Caches/PyCharm?0
rm -rfv ~/Library/Application\ Support/PyCharm?0
rm -rfv ~/Library/Logs/PyCharm?0
```

Answer (score 20):

Incase if pycharm is installed using `snap package` then you could remove it by running following commands:

```
sudo snap remove [pycharm-professional|pycharm-community]
rm -rf ~/.PyCharm2017.3
rm -rf ~/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains/pycharm/
```

replace `.PyCharm2017.3` with your installed version.

Answer (score 19):

If you installed by ./pycharm.sh

Remove all folder and files below :

```
/usr/local/bin/charm => should rm with sudo
~/.Pycharm<version>
~/.local/share/icons/jetbrains-pycharm.png
~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop
~/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains/
```

And now you can reinstall new version, or having a clean pc without pycharm.

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
sudo snap remove pycharm-professional pycharm-community
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not enough

Comment: Why?@ArthurHenriqueDellaFraga

Comment: Actually, you're right, @baponkar. I've uninstalled and reinstalled it and thought there were some left files after this command, but it is the [official way described](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html?section=Linux#snap)

Comment: This worked for me after i rebooted the machine.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo find / -name *PyCharm*
```

Delete all output directories.

For example:

```
$ sudo find / -name *PyCharm*
[sudo] password for MY_USERNAME:
/home/MY_USERNAME/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1
/home/MY_USERNAME/.PyCharmCE2019.1
$ rm -rf /home/MY_USERNAME/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1 /home/MY_USERNAME/.PyCharmCE2019.1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The given command does not delete anything

Answer (score 4):

As Pycharm doesn't have any install or uninstall program for ubuntu, the best way to delete it completely is by deleting the directory into which you have unpacked it and the .PyCharmx.x directory.

Answer (score 4):

if you have installed using **./pycharm.sh** then

press ctrl+H to see the hidden folders in Home
then go to .config
then JetBrains
there you delete the PyCharm folder

Now you can reinstall pycharm or enjoy your pycharm free PC :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu you can do

1. `sudo rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm*`
2. `sudo rm -rf ~/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains/`

Answer (score 2):

I see some of the answers pointing to `~/Library/*` locations which I don't have by default in Ubuntu (specifically 18.04 Bionic Beaver), and maybe pertinent to MacOS systems.

For Ubuntu, here's my list of commands (for a standalone installation):

```
1. Delete the main app (snap|toolbox app|standalone) **see snap uninstallation cmds above)

# Clear caches and remnant files:
2. Remove the following dirs:
${HOME}/.config/JetBrains/<product><version>
${HOME}/.cache/JetBrains/<product><version>
${HOME}/.local/share/JetBrains/<product><version>
${HOME}/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains/*
```

Example:

```
~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3
~/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3
~/.local/share/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal (shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+T) in your ubuntu system and try this command:

```sh
sudo snap remove pycharm-community
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, is a little convenience to leave this hidden file for update "major" installation: for example, since PyCharm Community Edition 2.4 to 2.6, I found this in home directory: PyCharmCE2018.2; the installer suggests use (default) or ignore.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal as common user

1. `$rm -d -r ~/.PyCharm2019.3`

run same command as root user

1. `$sudo  su`
2. `$rm -d -r ~/.PyCharm2019.3`

note PyCharm2019.3 replaced with your PyCharm version

Answer (score 0):

You can follow their official documentation, they've mentioned the proper way to [Uninstall PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html) depends on the method you used to install it.

- [Uninstall using the Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html#toolbox)
- [Uninstall a standalone instance](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html#standalone)

  - Windows
  - macOS
  - Linux
- [Uninstall silently on Windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html#silent)
- [Uninstall the snap package on Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html#snap)

  - Professional Edition
  - Community Edition
  - Educational Edition