# How can I remove pycharm from my ubuntu machine?

Tags: pycharm, ubuntu-16.04

[image]

following one question on stack overflow I have tried these
commands but no luck.

```
$ sudo rm -fv /usr/local/bin/charm

$ sudo rm -rfv ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm?0

$ sudo rm -rfv ~/Library/Caches/PyCharm?0

$ sudo rm -rfv ~/Library/Application\ Support/PyCharm?0

$ sudo rm -rfv ~/Library/Logs/PyCharm?0

$ sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/pycharm.md5sums
```

I also tried to go inside pycharm folder but there delete option was disabled.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Pycharm completely , Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913471/remove-pycharm-completely-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Finally able to delete some files and folders which were related to pycharm by following these steps:

1. Open Ubuntu Software Center
2. Click on all software
3. On search bar, type pycharm.
4. Remove it.

But still few are left. could be seen in the latest screenshot.

Comment: there is not `pycharm` in ubuntu software center.

Comment: It will be when you download :)

Answer (score 3):

Run this code for community version of PyCharm on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo snap remove pycharm-community
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, pycharm can be removed from an ubuntu machine by deleting the installation documents directly. Try the following steps:

1. Find the hidden files under the dir:`/home` via `Ctrl + H`, and then remove the folder`.PyCharmCE2017.2`(it's the corresponding folder name on my machine)
2. Remove the remaining installation files in your installation path

Note that the third-party packages can be uninstalled inside pycharm before your uninstallation(or see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598162/how-to-permanently-remove-pycharm-community))

Comment: that I did already still when I type locate pycharm, It shows me  bunch of files and folders of pycharm.(see the screenshot)

Comment: @ShekharRamola, the ubuntu terminal could not show the full list. Try `Ctrl + H` in the step 1.

Comment: @Curname, I know buddy. It was one of those hidden folder which I have deleted already.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ubuntu Make to install Pycharm Community Edition

```
sudo umake ide pycharm
```

Remove Pycharm with this command

```
sudo umake ide pycharm --remove
```