# Delete PyCharm and all associated directories

Tags: python, pycharm, uninstallation

PyCharm Version 2019.1.3
OS: macOS 10.15 Beta

I am trying to delete PyCharm and all associated directories. I did some research and found for example this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913471/remove-pycharm-completely-ubuntu):

> rm -fv /usr/local/bin/charm
>
> rm -rfv ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm?0
>
> rm -rfv ~/Library/Caches/PyCharm?0
>
> rm -rfv ~/Library/Application\ Support/PyCharm?0
>
> rm -rfv ~/Library/Logs/PyCharm?0

which recommends to locate and remove the PyCharm directories in the Preferences, Caches, Application Support and Logs directories. But for me there are no PyCharm folders. But when I try to reinstall PyCharm, I don't need to select the installation folder the dark or light mode and so on and I even takes me to the project I haven't closed the last time, so I am assuming there still have to some files. So how do I locate and delete those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `PyCharm?0` with `PyCharm2019.1`. The old pattern doesn't match the new version.