# how to remove pycharm-professional from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: pycharm, installation

I install pycharm-professional after downloaded from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux),

I choose `Professional` not `Community`

then used ./pycharm.sh

I would like to remove it completely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Pycharm completely , Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913471/remove-pycharm-completely-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unpacked sources. Relevant docs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html?section=Linux#standalone

Answer (score 0):

For my Ubuntu 20.04 machine it took quite a few steps to completely remove the Professional and also the Community version. Here's what I had to do

First follow the official uninstallation guide -

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html?section=Linux

Which tells you to remove the following directories:

Syntax

```
~/.config/JetBrains/<product><version>
~/.cache/JetBrains/<product><version>
```

I did that, but it was not completely removing as I could launch PyCharm again from the Desktop Menu

So then I ran

`sudo find / -name *PyCharm*`

It may take 3 to 4 minutes to finish the searching process and and output the result in the Terminal.

Then for me gave the following kind of output

```
/home/<user-name>/.local/share/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1
/home/<user-name>/.local/share/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1
/home/<user-name>/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gnome-software/icons/e5454464646
646ee7fa5a196e1707d9e47107ee-PyCharmCore256.png
/home/<user-name>/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gnome-software/icons/188057e734443468686446890ec081e0eaafe8f4e88-PyCharmEdu256.png
```

I manually deleted all of the above files and folders.

Even after this, still I could launch PyCharm from menu. So I did search for "pycharm" in my `/usr/shar/` directory and the search result found the following file.

`/usr/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop`

The above file contained the configurations to launch PyCharm by referring to the correct launch file from my previously downloaded PyCharm file. And the above `jetbrains-pycharm.desktop` file gets created when from withing PyCharm you do

**Tools > Create Desktop Entry...**

The content  of this file would be similar to below containing the full path of the `pycharm.sh` file to launch PyCharm (this ofcourse will be different for you depending on the location of your downloaded .tar file from PyCharm's website ) -

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Professional Edition
Icon=/home/<user-name>/Downloads/pycharm-professional-2020.1.3/pycharm-2020.1.3/bin/pycharm.svg
Exec="/home/<user-name>/Downloads/pycharm-professional-2020.1.3/pycharm-2020.1.3/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
Comment=Python IDE for Professional Developers
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm
```

So I manually deleted the above file

After the above step, **PyCharm Professional** was no more coming in the launch menu , but still **PyCharm Community Edition** was coming in the launch menu.

So in the very root directory "/" I did a regular search with `Ctrl + Find` for the term ‘charm’ and got a search result for `/snap/pycharm-community`

But you can NOT delete this file (`/snap/pycharm-community`) normally even after opening the directory with `sudo` access with `$sudo natilus`

So to remove this file you have to do

`sudo snap remove pycharm-community`

as per - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html#snap

And now finally I could fully uninstall PyCharm from my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.